# How to get the ExpressJS request and response object in LoopbackJS?

Tags: loopbackjs

I am facing a problem finding the request and response objects given by ExpressJS. I made an endpoint in /server/boot/root.js like bellow. I don't want this endpoint to bind with any model.

```
  router.get('/playing/:param1/:param2',function(ctx){
    console.log(ctx.req); // prints undefined
  } );
```

How to get the regular ExpressJS request and response object so that I can handle this by my own will?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added custom routes with

```
router.get('/playing/:param1/:param2',function(req,res){
    var param1 = req.params.param1;
    var param2 = req.params.param2;
    console.log(param1,param2); // should print something
});
```

and I did it inside /server/boot/root.js so that should be fine.